# Extending Array only when the element type is of a specific type

Tags: swift

I want to extend the array type only when its elements is of a specific type. In this case I'm using instances of EKCalendar.

This does not work:

```
public extension Array where Generator.Element : EKCalendar{

}
```

But this Does:

```
public extension CollectionType where Generator.Element : EKCalendar{

}
```

Why is it I can only do this with a protocol ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While extending `Array` you cannot access `Generator.Element` because it's part of the `CollectionType` protocol, you need to use `Element`:

```
public extension Array where Element: EKCalendar {
   //....
}
```